# Pandas: Write all re.search results to csv from BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I have these beginnings of a Python `pandas` script that searches for values in  on Google and grabs any PDF links it can find on the first page.

I have two questions, listed below.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(["Shakespeare", "Beowulf"], columns=["Search"])    

print "Searching for PDFs ..."

hdr = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3",
    "Accept-Encoding": "none",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
    "Connection": "keep-alive"}

def crawl(search):
    google = "http://www.google.com/search?q="
    url = google + search + "+" + "PDF"
    req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=hdr)

    pdf_links = None
    placeholder = None #just a column placeholder

    try:
        page = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
        cite = soup.find_all("cite", attrs={"class":"_Rm"})
        for link in cite:
            all_links = re.search(r".+", link.text).group().encode("utf-8")
            if all_links.endswith(".pdf"):
                pdf_links = re.search(r"(.+)pdf$", all_links).group()
            print pdf_links

    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print e.fp.read()

    return pd.Series([pdf_links, placeholder])

df[["PDF links", "Placeholder"]] = df["Search"].apply(crawl)

df.to_csv(FileName, index=False, delimiter=",")
```

---

The results from `print pdf_links` will be:

```
davidlucking.com/documents/Shakespeare-Complete%20Works.pdf
sparks.eserver.org/books/shakespeare-tempest.pdf
www.w3.org/People/maxf/.../hamlet.pdf
www.w3.org/People/maxf/.../hamlet.pdf
www.w3.org/People/maxf/.../hamlet.pdf
www.w3.org/People/maxf/.../hamlet.pdf
www.w3.org/People/maxf/.../hamlet.pdf
www.w3.org/People/maxf/.../hamlet.pdf
www.w3.org/People/maxf/.../hamlet.pdf
calhoun.k12.il.us/teachers/wdeffenbaugh/.../Shakespeare%20Sonnets.pdf
www.yorku.ca/inpar/Beowulf_Child.pdf
www.yorku.ca/inpar/Beowulf_Child.pdf
https://is.muni.cz/el/1441/.../2._Beowulf.pdf
https://is.muni.cz/el/1441/.../2._Beowulf.pdf
https://is.muni.cz/el/1441/.../2._Beowulf.pdf
https://is.muni.cz/el/1441/.../2._Beowulf.pdf
www.penguin.com/static/pdf/.../beowulf.pdf
www.neshaminy.org/cms/lib6/.../380/text.pdf
www.neshaminy.org/cms/lib6/.../380/text.pdf
sparks.eserver.org/books/beowulf.pdf
```

And the csv output will look like:

```
Search         PDF Links
Shakespeare    calhoun.k12.il.us/teachers/wdeffenbaugh/.../Shakespeare%20Sonnets.pdf
Beowulf        sparks.eserver.org/books/beowulf.pdf
```

---

Questions:

- Is there a way to write all of the results as rows to the csv instead of
  just the bottom one? And if possible, include the value in `Search` for each row that corresponds to `"Shakespeare"` or `"Beowulf"`?
- How can I write out the full pdf links without long links automatically abbreviating with `"..."`?

Comment: what search term are you using?

Comment: Hi @PadraicCunningham! I am using "Shakespeare" and "Beowulf" as searchterms (from the DataFrame).

Comment: Wrong link http://pastebin.com/Z38X8hWU , unless you actually want a dataframe it can also all be done using the csv module

Comment: Thanks! This looks about right :), but I can't contain the getting of the DF inside the function, as in my original code I'm getting a list of search terms from a csv which I select with `os.listdir`. So therefore I use this method of crawling the DF: `df[["PDF links", "Placeholder"]] = df["Search"].apply(crawl)`

Comment: Keeping `df` to the function only will yield: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df' referenced before assignment`

Comment: You Pass in the df to the function. I will add an alternative when i get back in my como

Comment: So your list of search words comes from one of your columns?

Comment: Yep, in the pastebin it's "ISIN" if you saw the link.

Comment: Do you want to create a new column for the links or add to an existing?

Comment: Create a new column :)

Comment: Adding the column is easy, adding new elements to Search for each pdf link is not so easy http://pastebin.com/UrjUAurF

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks, this gives me a list of pdfs in each cell at least. I guess I can use that as my answer if you want to update the answer. I will work on trying to find a way to insert new rows for each item in the list.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I used this implementation that works, based on your solution. You can check it and paste it to your answer if you like: http://pastebin.com/RNep5LQm

Comment: I was leaning towards something similar but thought there must be an easier way, I will have a look tomorrow again when I get a chance and see if I can find a simple method

Comment: Maybe some variation of this would work http://pastebin.com/8CD31YN7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you all the proper pdf links using `soup.find_all("a",href=True)` and save them in a Dataframe and to a csv:

```
hdr = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3",
    "Accept-Encoding": "none",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
    "Connection": "keep-alive"}


def crawl(columns=None, *search):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns= columns)
    for term in search:
        google = "http://www.google.com/search?q="
        url = google + term + "+" + "PDF"
        req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=hdr)
        try:
            page = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
            pdfs = []
            links = soup.find_all("a",href=True)
            for link in links:
                lk = link["href"]
                if lk.endswith(".pdf"):
                     pdfs.append((term, lk))
            df2 = pd.DataFrame(pdfs, columns=columns)
            df = df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
        except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
            print e.fp.read()
    return df


df = crawl(["Search", "PDF link"],"Shakespeare","Beowulf")
df.to_csv("out.csv",index=False)
```

out.csv:

```
Search,PDF link
Shakespeare,http://davidlucking.com/documents/Shakespeare-Complete%20Works.pdf
Shakespeare,http://www.w3.org/People/maxf/XSLideMaker/hamlet.pdf
Shakespeare,http://sparks.eserver.org/books/shakespeare-tempest.pdf
Shakespeare,https://phillipkay.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/william-shakespeare-plays.pdf
Shakespeare,http://www.artsvivants.ca/pdf/eth/activities/shakespeare_overview.pdf
Shakespeare,http://triggs.djvu.org/djvu-editions.com/SHAKESPEARE/SONNETS/Download.pdf
Beowulf,http://www.yorku.ca/inpar/Beowulf_Child.pdf
Beowulf,https://is.muni.cz/el/1441/podzim2013/AJ2RC_STAL/2._Beowulf.pdf
Beowulf,http://teacherweb.com/IL/Steinmetz/MottramM/Beowulf---Seamus-Heaney.pdf
Beowulf,http://www.penguin.com/static/pdf/teachersguides/beowulf.pdf
Beowulf,http://www.neshaminy.org/cms/lib6/PA01000466/Centricity/Domain/380/text.pdf
Beowulf,http://www.sparknotes.com/free-pdfs/uscellular/download/beowulf.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

To get PDF links, you're looking for these selectors:

```py
for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):

  # check if PDF is present via according CSS class OR use try/except instead
  if result.select_one('.ZGwO7'):
    pdf_file = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
```

*`CSS` selectors [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). Have a look at [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to grab `CSS` selectors by clicking on the desired element in your browser*.

---

To save them to `CSV`, you're looking for this:

```py
# store all links from a for loop
pdfs = []

# create PDF Link column and append PDF links from a pdfs list()
df = pd.DataFrame({'PDF Link': pdfs})

# save to csv and delete default pandas index column. Done!
df.to_csv('PDFs.csv', index=False)
```

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Search-scrape-and-download-PDF-files-locally#bs4_result.py) (*also shows how to save locally*):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "best lasagna recipe:pdf"
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

pdfs = []

for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):

  # check if PDF is present via according CSS class
  if result.select_one('.ZGwO7'):
    pdf_file = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
    pdfs.append(pdf_file)

# creates PDF Link column and appends PDF links from a pdfs list()
df = pd.DataFrame({'PDF Link': pdfs})
df.to_csv('Bs4_PDFs.csv', index=False)

-----------
# from CSV
'''
PDF Link
http://www.bakersedge.com/PDF/Lasagna.pdf
http://greatgreens.ca/recipes/Recipe%20-%20Worlds%20Best%20Lasagna.pdf
https://liparifoods.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/lipari-foods-holiday-recipes.pdf
...
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that rather than creating everything from scratch, figuring out why certain things don't work as expected, and then maintain it over time, all that you need to do is to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want. It might be also more readable and quickly understand what's going on inside the code.

Code to integrate with your example:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os
import pandas as pd

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "best lasagna recipe:pdf",
  "hl": "en"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

pdfs = []

# iterate over organic results and check if .pdf file type exists in link
for result in results['organic_results']:
  if '.pdf' in result['link']:
    pdf_file = result['link']
    pdfs.append(pdf_file)

df = pd.DataFrame({'PDF Link': pdfs})
df.to_csv('SerpApi_PDFs.csv', index=False)

-----------
# from CSV
'''
PDF Link
http://www.bakersedge.com/PDF/Lasagna.pdf
http://greatgreens.ca/recipes/Recipe%20-%20Worlds%20Best%20Lasagna.pdf
https://liparifoods.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/lipari-foods-holiday-recipes.pdf
...
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.